# Achieve a dataframe from a dynamic list of lists

Tags: r

This code works for me, but I am trying to improve my coding and am looking for advice on how to improve it. Specifically I want to simplify this so that perhaps I can have a dynamically updating dataframe that tracks the "site" that I am on, and the "cutoff" value that I am on, and records the calculations for that site/cutoff value combination. Right now, it's a little clumsy and admittedly very ugly. Through this process, though, I learned about "assign" for creating assigning variables on the fly. I think I just need maybe one or two more concepts before I can really clean this up.

```
calcs <- function(site, cutoff){} #Returns a 4 item list

cutoffmatrix <- c(0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015) #matrix that I want to loop through

for(i in 1:length(cutoffmatrix)){ #Loop that uses my function for cutoffmatrix value
  test <- list()
  co <- cutoffmatrix[i]
  assign(paste("TC", i, sep = ""), calcs("TC", co))
}

l_TC <- list(TC1, TC2, TC3, TC4) #combines the loop results into a list for that site

library(plyr)
df_TC <- ldply (l_TC, data.frame) #transform lists of lists into dataframe

for(i in 1:length(cutoffmatrix)){ #same thing, but for next site
  test <- list()
  co <- cutoffmatrix[i]
  assign(paste("DC", i, sep = ""), calcs("DC", co))
}

l_DC <- list(DC1, DC2, DC3, DC4)
df_DC <- ldply(l_DC, data.frame)

final <- rbind (df_TC, df_DC) #combines both site's results into a dataframe
final <- cbind(final, cutoffmatrix) #adds cutoff values to dataframe
namelist <- c("TC", "TC", "TC", "TC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC") #adds sites to dataframe
final <- cbind(final, namelist)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reviewing line-by-line:

```
cutoffmatrix <- c(0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015)
```

If this is a vector, why call it a matrix? I would just call it just `cutoffs`.

```
for(i in 1:length(cutoffmatrix)){
    test <- list()
    co <- cutoffmatrix[i]
    assign(paste("TC", i, sep = ""), calcs("TC", co))
}
```

The use of `1:length(cutoffmatrix)` in a `for` loop is a common mistake. You'll probably agree that, by design, the code in the loop will be executed `length(cutoffmatrix)`. Well, that's not exactly always the case. In particular, when `cutoffmatrix` is empty: `cutoffmatrix <- c()`. You would want the loop to be executed `length(cutoffmatrix)` i.e. zero times. However, in this unfortunate case, `1:length(cutoffmatrix)` would evaluate to `1:0` i.e. `c(1, 0)`. Instead of zero iteration, you'll have two and likely cause an error. Instead of `1:length(cutoffmatrix)`, you should use `seq_along(cutoffmatrix)` or `seq_len(length(cutoffmatrix))`. Both `seq_along` and `seq_len` will do the right thing when their input is empty or zero respectively.

The use of `assign` to dynamically create objects is, excuse my word, an abomination. I'll try to show you a couple reasons why. Via your loop, you have managed to create four objects: `TC1`, `TC2`, `TC3`, `TC4` which you later use in your code:

```
l_TC <- list(TC1, TC2, TC3, TC4)
```

What would happen if instead of 4 objects, you had 2000 objects? Do you see yourself typing `l_TC <- list(TC1, TC2, TC3, TC4, ..., TC2000)`? No. Maybe you will find about the `get` or `mget` function so you can do:

```
l_TC <- mget(paste("TC", seq_along(cutoffmatrix), sep = ""))
```

But wait. This is still abominable. For one reason, you could be creating thousands of such objects and "polluting" your environment with similar objects. Why not put them all into a single object? Also imagine someone coming across `TC1` in your environment and searching for "TC1" through your code to find where it got created: no luck. Finally, having to use `mget` to indirectly refer to the `TC*` objects is a bit complex, no? And you have to remember that the objects are labelled `1` through `length(cutoffmatrix)`...

So what is the alternative? Do not create `length(cutoffmatrix)` objects but just one object: a list containing `length(cutoffmatrix)` items. How? Use `lapply` or `Map`:

```
l_TC <- lapply(cutoffvec, calcs, site = "TC")
```

Look how shorter this is! And in the following, 1) your code will only use `l_TC` to refer to those `4` or `2000` objects stored within 2) Someone stumbling upon `l_TC` in your environment will see exactly where it was created in your code. By all means, please never use `assign` again and erase that function from your memory!

Next:

```
library(plyr)
df_TC <- ldply (l_TC, data.frame) #transform lists of lists into dataframe
```

So this converts the lists into data.frames and rbinds everything together. You do not really need `plyr` for that. You can first turn the lists into data.frames by doing `lapply(l_TC, as.data.frame)`. And you can do the binding using `do.call(rbind, ...)`, so:

```
df_TC <- do.call(rbind, lapply(l_TC, as.data.frame))
```

But before doing that: Why do you need to convert the list items to data.frames, then bind? Could you instead rewrite `calcs` so that it returns a data.frame? And better, could `calc` take a vector of cutoffs instead of a single value and return a data.frame with `length(cutoffs)` rows?

```
final <- rbind(df_TC, df_DC)
final <- cbind(final, cutoffmatrix)
```

Instead of having to add `cutoffmatrix`, could `calcs` already include a `cutoff` item in its output list?

```
namelist <- c("TC", "TC", "TC", "TC", "DC", "DC", "DC", "DC")
final <- cbind(final, namelist)
```

This code has a baked-in assumption that there are four cutoffs. If you were to modify `cutoffmatrix` so its length is not four, then this would break. Instead, you could do:

```
namelist <- rep(c("TC", "DC"), each = length(cutoffmatrix))
```

Still, not great. Similar to above, the best would be if `calcs` could include a `site = site` item in its output list.

Last. What if instead of two sites `"TC"` and `"DC"` you had many more websites to use? How could you modify your code so you do not have to write `"TC"` or `"DC"` more than once and have to rely on creating too many objects? Maybe use some of the concepts I have shown you? Good luck!

Comment: This is brilliant thank you so much for taking the time to review my code. I keep forgetting how useful lapply and sapply are...I need to get a better intuition for their uses and this is really helpful.